# Adjust divs vertically with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page with a forum-like comment section, and I would like to adjust the divs (comments) with CSS one on top of the other, like the float:left feature but vertically.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Divs automatically stack up. Can you be more specific? Also do you need to support older browsers or is flexbox in the mix? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Alredy found the answer, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is clear your floats. 'float: left; clear: both;'